# How to click at position in Canvas using Javascript?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, canvas

I want to click Canvas element have id is `myCanvas` width: 500, height: 200.

In Javascript, have any method to do this?

Using `Page Ruler` - Chrome extension to get position include parameter `x`, `y`.

I tried with code:

```
function relMouseCoords(event){
    var totalOffsetX = 220;
    var totalOffsetY = 100;
    var canvasX = 500;
    var canvasY = 200;
    var currentElement = this;

    do{
        totalOffsetX += currentElement.offsetLeft - currentElement.scrollLeft;
        totalOffsetY += currentElement.offsetTop - currentElement.scrollTop;
    }
    while(currentElement = currentElement.offsetParent)

    canvasX = event.pageX - totalOffsetX;
    canvasY = event.pageY - totalOffsetY;
    console.log(canvasX, convastY);
    return {x:canvasX, y:canvasY}
}
HTMLCanvasElement.prototype.relMouseCoords = relMouseCoords;
```

Answer (score 0):

Click on any element via JS can be done with **[trigger](http://api.jquery.com/trigger/)**.

Using jQuery:

```
x_coord = 1;
y_coord = 1;

var e = jQuery.Event( "mousedown", { pageX: x_coord, pageY: y_coord } );
$('#myCanvas').trigger(e);

// execute more code
x_coord = 255;
y_coord = 255;

var e = jQuery.Event( "mouseup", { pageX: x_coord, pageY: y_coord } );
$('#myCanvas').trigger(e);
```

Comment: Hey @semanser, I tried with your code but it was not working. You can see the demo at http://imgur.com/a/NE4Ze. I test with link: http://codepen.io/r0ysy0301/full/grjaOp/

Comment: If it working, it must click in this canvas and appear any `confetti`.